# Xpath/CSS not recognizing while testing the options listed under a SPAN

Tags: java, css, selenium, xpath

I am new to automation testing (Selenium, Java) and learning it by watching the videos from youtube. I was able to get the basic understanding. I was checking on a website where the options are available at left side bar. there are nearly 7 options available.. I am not able to use the Click(); option using the xpath or CSS. I was trying to add the scripts to click on the options one after another.

Below is the HTML available. Thanks

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7qAE.png)

Comment: Show us your test

Comment: //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@href=\'sidebarnav\']/li[3]/a")).click();
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@href=\'sidebarnav\']/li[7]/a")).click();

//driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sidebarnav > li:nth-child(4) > a > span")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sidebarnav\"]/li[3]")).click();

Tried using the above scripts. I have added the HTML codes as an image and attached to the question

Comment: You can go slowly. Try `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#sidebarnav"))` and see what it returns. Then add `> li`, `>li:nth-child(4)` and so on.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.